# Can independence numbers of box products of cycles increase after stabilizing?

Tags: graphs, information-theory

Is there an evidence or a proof that the independence of strong products of graphs can increase after stabilizing?

I am interested in odd cycles only.

Let $C_n$ be an odd cycle and $\alpha(G)$ represent independence number of a graph $G$.

Let $C_n^m$ be $m$-times strong product of $C_n$.

Now say $$\alpha(C_n^{m_1m_2})=\alpha(C_n^{m_1})^{m_2}.$$ 
That is $m_1m_2$-times strong product of $C_n$ has same independence number as $m_1$-times strong product of $C_n$ raised to $m_2$. For example,  $\alpha(C_5^{4})=\alpha(C_5^{2})^{2}=25$.

Then is it possible $$\alpha(C_n^{m_1m_2m_3})>\alpha(C_n^{m_1})^{m_2m_3}\mbox{ or }\alpha(C_n^{m_1m_2m_3})>\alpha(C_n^{m_1m_2})^{m_3}?$$

In the example above, we have violation of strict inequality since we have:$$\alpha(C_5^{8})=\alpha(C_5^{2})^{4}=625\mbox{ or }\alpha(C_5^{8})=\alpha(C_5^{4})^{2}=625.$$

Comment: I don't think "evidence or proof" is the correct terminology. You are looking for an *example* or a *disproof*.

Comment: Some evidence is given in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0608021. The same methods could perhaps be used to generate a counterexample of the type you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you. But that paper seems to talk about general graphs.  Although you are correct. It should work for all types.